# Wrong Date in DatePicker

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, uidatepicker

I am using a `DatePicker` to select a date entered by the user.

[DatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDXzM.png)

The settings for my `DatePicker` are:

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVf3I.png)

However it always added 3 hours to the date selected by the user

```
MyItem.limitTime = DatePickerLimitTime.Value;
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSDateFormatter` to format your date before printing it, also set correct `TimeZone`

```
myDatePicker.TimeZone = NSTimeZone.LocalTimeZone;
myDatePicker.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    lbl.Text = NSDateFormatter.ToLocalizedString(myDatePicker.Date, NSDateFormatterStyle.Full, NSDateFormatterStyle.Medium);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: If I want to change a value that is declared in my Model, and in View I am using a Bind, how should I do it?
In view
`Set.Bind (myDatePicker) .To (vm => vm.valueDatePicker);`

Model
`Public INC <DateTime> valueDatePicker = new NC <DateTime> ();`

Comment: Which binding framework you are using, can you provide a link?